# How can I resolve the 'System.EmailException: SendEmail failed

Tags: apex

"How can I resolve the 'System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, The ID provided is not of types ContentVersion or Document.: [entityAttachments, 0695g00000Jek1RAAR]' error in Salesforce Apex when attempting to send an email with attachments?"

This is my code

```
public class sendmail {
    
    Public void m1(){
        ContentDocument doc =[SELECT Id, Title FROM ContentDocument where Id='0695g00000Jek1RAAR'];
        List<id> docid= new List<id>();
        docid.add(doc.id);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        semail.setEntityAttachments(docid);
        semail.setSubject('Sham Resume');
        semail.setPlainTextBody('Kindly Check out the Attachment attached below');
        string[] sendto = new string[]{'sh*******'}; 
        semail.setToAddresses(sendto);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{semail});
   
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. The error clearly states that you have to use ContentVersion, but you are using ContentDocument.  Also see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setEntityAttachments).

Comment: @DavidCheng  Thank you for your assistance brother. Actually I sorted out the problem that the error here is I didn't select the right object where the document is stored. It's not a content version ; it's a Document Object. Once again thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't select the right object and ID where the document is stored. I could not find the Document object so I used the contentDocument object. However, the Document object is only available and visible in older version (Classic). I finally found that and uploaded the Custom document in the object and Changed the Object Selection to the Document and query in the Code